# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined when function is already defined

Tags: javascript, html

***I have a function which is defined but not working in my DOM.***

I am working with 2 files. Lets say, ***A.js*** and ***B.js***

In ***A.js*** I have some code like below.

```
(function() {
    var initData = {
        version: "1.0.0",
        host: "xyz.com",
        page_id: "someDynamicID",
    };
    function initVarData(initData) {
        if (!window.ABCD) {
            window.ABCD = initData;
        }
    }
    initVarData(initData);
})();

(function(d, id) {
    function appendToBody(d, el) {
        if (d.head) {
            d.head.appendChild(el);
        } else {
            setTimeout(appendToBody.bind(null, d, el), 500);
        }
    }
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        window.ABCD && ABCD.widgets.parse();
        return;
    }

    var js = d.createElement("script");
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "https://myserver.com/js/B.js";
    appendToBody(d, js);
})(document, "test");
```

In ***A.js*** I have defined some dynamic data (This ***A.js*** scripts is actually loading from a backend). Then ***A.js*** is calling ***B.js*** to load in the DOM.

In ***B.js*** I have some code like below

```
(function(window, document) {
  window.bng = function(buttonID) {
    var button = document.getElementById(buttonID);

    if (button) {
      button.addEventListener(
        "click",
        function() {
          alert("This alert is from B.js");
        },
        false
      );
    }
  };
})(window, document);
```

This function is updated in console but not updated in DOM.

In html I have called ***A.js*** and use bng("buttonId"). But I got error Uncaught ReferenceError: bng is not defined.

I have solved this problem with

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  bng("buttonId");
});
```

but I want to do without onLoad function. Facebook is using their function fbq like this in their SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I think, If you make script **B.js** load first (blocking script), the problem should be resolved.

Comment out the lines in A.js that tries to load B.js.

```
  // var js = d.createElement("script");
  // js.id = id;
  // js.async = true;
  // js.src = "https://myserver.com/js/B.js";
  // appendToBody(d, js);
```

And edit the HTML as below.

```
<head>
    <title>JS Tests</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/B.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/A.js"></script>
</head>
```

You can try the below snippet to see if it works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>JS Tests</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://codepen.io/nithinthampi/pen/abbWzqp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://codepen.io/nithinthampi/pen/OJJmPQa.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn_test">Click Me</button>
    <script>
        window.bng("btn_test");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to go the async way (Load B.js from A.js), One possible approach you can try.

Here the script **B.js** is loaded asynchronously.

So, even before the script is loaded and executed, the JS code you have added in your html will run and throw `Uncaught ReferenceError: bng is not defined`.

```
<body>
    <button id="btn_test">Click Me</button>
    <script>
        // The below code will throw an error as it runs before B.js completes its execution and initializes window.bng()
        window.bng("btn_test");
    </script>
</body>
```

In this case, we can define a function let's say `bng_test()` in **A.js** that's available on window before your application code executes

Make **A.js** synchronous and define the function `bng_test` in it.

```
<head>
    <script src="A.js"></script>
</head>
```

Application code can call this function `window.bng_test` defined in **A.js** instead of `window.bng` defined in **B.js**

Somewhere in **A.js**,  define an array (lets call it **event queue**) to store the calls from application until the actual function `window.bng` is ready.

The new function `window.bng_test` will add items to the **event queue** if `window.bng` is not ready, else call `window.bng`

```
const queue = [];
window.bng_test = function(elementId) {
    // Check if the function bng is initialized
    if(window.bng){
      bng(elementId);
    }
    // Add the element to the queue
    else{
      queue.push(elementId);
    }  
};
```

Now we could use a timer function to clear off the queue when **B.js** is executed and `window.bng` function is available.

```
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (window.bng) {
      while (queue.length > 0) {
        window.bng(queue.pop());
      }
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 500);
```

You might need to clear your timer on `window.beforeunload` as well to avoid memory leaks.

Pitfalls..

- Script **B.js** is slow and user closes the window / navigated away,
  calls will be lost.
- User has some calls in queue, **B.js** executed successfully, but
  user closed window / navigated away before timer clears the queue. In
  this case as well, you could make use of `window.beforeunload` to
  clear the queue.

Try the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>JS Tests</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://codepen.io/nithinthampi/pen/oNNZybP.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn_test">Click Me</button>
    <script>
        window.bng_test("btn_test");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```